# Is there a function like (MapboxMap.OnCameraIdleListener) in swift 4?

Tags: swift, mapbox

I switched form google map to MapBox and could not find a function like:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, idleAt cameraPosition: GMSCameraPosition) {
geocoder.reverseGeocodeCoordinate(cameraPosition.target) { (response, error) in
  guard error == nil else {
    return
  }

  if let result = response?.firstResult() {
    let marker = GMSMarker()
    marker.position = cameraPosition.target
    marker.title = result.lines?[0]
    marker.snippet = result.lines?[1]
    marker.map = mapView
  }
}
 }
}
```

which gives a coordinates form center of map when user stops moving the map, I also found that there is a function of mapBox which gives same result for android (`MapboxMap.OnCameraIdleListener`) but I coulden't find a fucntion similar to this in mapbox for swift.

Is there a function for swift which gives similar kind of result? If yes then what might it be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn’t an exact match for the function but the `mapView` has a property called `centerCoordinate` that returns the value you want.

```swift
let mapCenter = mapView.centerCoordinate
```

Changing/setting this property will reset the `mapView’s` centre. This can be animated if required.

If you want to know when the map has been moved and then stopped you can use the delegate method:

```swift
func mapView(_ mapView: MGLMapView, regionDidChangeAnimated: Bool) {
    // Get your centre coordinate here.
}
```

> This method is called whenever the currently displayed map camera has finished changing.